# Looking for a way to connect wires to a breakout board without soldering

Tags: diy, usb-c, keyboard, usb-host, breakout

I'm looking to get a custom keyboard cable but there's a catch - my keyboard cable is currently hardwired. The solutions I've come up with are either to use a janky solution where I use solder splices to connect the wires inside of my mechanical keyboard to a USB C Female to USB 2.0 or micro USB male adapter, however this is janky as I said before. The only other solution I've found is to solder the wires to a USB type C breakout board, however I do not have a soldering iron and that would drive up the cost of the whole thing by a massive amount.

While I'm sure you guys will probably recommend that I get a soldering iron due to how undeniably useful they can be, this is more of a one time thing so getting a soldering iron specifically for this is a bit iffy. I was wondering how I could do this without soldering and still with a pretty reliable connection.

Comment: please post a picture of the board in question

Comment: something like this https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/adafruit-industries-llc/4090/9951930?utm_adgroup=Adapter%2C%20Breakout%20Boards&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_Prototyping%2C%20Fabrication%20Products_NEW&utm_term=&utm_content=Adapter%2C%20Breakout%20Boards&gclid=Cj0KCQiAh4j-BRCsARIsAGeV12AQgJslJQlly4jnNYFkItodzsjVN-7b8HPc89jMGU94TkX3ngo1wcsaAiO0EALw_wcB

Comment: soldering irons start at 10c (heat a nail up using a gas flame)

Comment: don't forget that you may need a soldering iron for other projects, so it may make sense to buy one ... or,  make one, as @Jasen suggested ... wrap some heavy copper around a long nail and attach a wooden handle ... the copper would store heat ... a flattened copper pipe would work ... put the nail in the middle before you flatten it, then kind of roll it up

Comment: [A cheap piece of crap,](https://www.amazon.com/GLE2016-Soldering-Adjustable-Temperature-Different/dp/B01N413T8U/ref=mp_s_a_1_31?dchild=1&keywords=soldering+iron+25w&qid=1606617797&refinements=p_36%3A1253528011&rnid=1243644011&s=hi&sprefix=soldering+iron+25&sr=1-31) but it'll do what you need for a one time deal.

Answer (score 1):

Google `friction fit pin headers`.

[image]